# Sybase insert statement with subqueries of select

Tags: sql, insert, subquery, sybase

I am trying to do an `insert` with subqueries but this `insert` fails:

```
insert into 
    TABLE_A(COL_A, COL_B, COL_C, COL_D, COL_E, COL_F)
    values (
        1, 
        (select COL_B from TABLE_B where user_name = 'foo'),
        (select COL_C from TABLE_C where age = 25),
        2,3,4);
```

I tried to write it different but it still fails.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want `insert . . . select` syntax.  The `values` is not needed:

```
insert into TABLE_A(COL_A, COL_B, COL_C, COL_D, COL_E, COL_F) 
    select 1, (select COL_B from TABLE_B where user_name = 'foo'),
           (select COL_C from TABLE_C where age = 25),
           2, 3, 4;
```

You could also write this as a `cross join` if you prefer:

```
insert into TABLE_A(COL_A, COL_B, COL_C, COL_D, COL_E, COL_F) 
    select 1, b.COL_B, c.COL_C,
           2, 3, 4;
    from (select COL_B from TABLE_B where user_name = 'foo') b cross join
         (select COL_C from TABLE_C where age = 25) c
```